# Consultas con MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Buenas tardes tengo la siguiente inquietud:

Tengo definido un POJO como lo ven a continuación:

```
@Id
private String idInformacion;
@Indexed(direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING)
private Pais pais;
private Date fechaCreacion;
private String nombre;
private String sexo;
private Date fechaNacimiento;
private List<Preferencias> preferencias;
private String numTelefono;
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String usuario;
private List<RedesSociales> redes;
private String contraseniaTW;
private String contraseniaFB;
private String contraseniaIG;
private Grupo grupo;
private String paqChip;
private String email;
private String contraseniaMail;
private String fuente;
private Date fechaRecarga;
```

Como pueden observar los atributos  `Preferencias`  y  `RedesSociales` están definidos como tipo List, para acceder a los valores almacenados en la B.D uso un interfaz que extiende de la clase `MongoRepository` y uso el metodo `findAll()`.
Ahora el problema es que estos atributos antes mencionados son retornados de esta manera: (Ya que tienen más de un valor) 
`[Preferencias(nombrePref=Rock), Preferencias(nombrePref=Tatuajes)]`

Esto no sería un problema pero al momento de presentarlos en la página web es molesto verlos de esta manera. Mi pregunta es como podría hacer para que estos valores que están en una lista solo sacar el valor interno, es decir en preferencias solo obtener `Rock` o `Tatuajes` ya que es el valor que me interesa presentar en la página web, lo que intente fue ya que el `finAll` es un List sacar los valores con sus respectivos get pero a gran cantidad de datos no me parece eficiente. Se puede generar una consulta en Mongo para obtener todos los valores almacenados pero los atributos definidos como List traerlos como un String concatenado?  es decir algo así = `Rock - Tatuajes`

Comment: Por favor, no publiques pantallazos del código, pega el código como tal. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate listo ya quite la captura

Comment: @Bryan Saltos Lograste resolver el problema?

Comment: @Raul Cacacho así es use la lista que me devuelve el mongorepository y mediante un <code> for each </code> en la vista recorrí la lista que me regresa de preferencias extrayendo el nombre con su respectivo metodo <code>get</code>